# How change array result hierarchy in Doctrine results with joined tables

Tags: php, sql, symfony, multidimensional-array, doctrine

My query with join: (in entities are NOT relations)

```
    $query = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->select('f');

    $query->leftJoin(IntranetType::class, 'it', 'WITH', 'it.flyerLayoutType = f.flyerLayout');
    $query->addSelect('it');

    $query->orderBy('f.filename');
    $query->addOrderBy('it.flyerLayoutType');

    // $flyers = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult(); <-- fist try
    $flyers = $query->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

And result array is in format:

```
array(149) {
[0]=>
array(9) {
 data from table with alias f
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
 data from table with alias it
}
[2]=>
array(9) {
 data from table with alias f
}
[3]=>
array(4) {
 data from table with alias it
}
```

But i need format like this:

```
array(149) {
[0]=>
array(9) {
 data from table with alias f
  ['joined table']=>
  array(4) {
   data from table with alias it
  }
}

[1]=>
array(9) {
 data from table with alias f
  ['joined table']=>
  array(4) {
   data from table with alias it
  }
}
```

Just hierarchy... One key in array = one flyer (one item) and with in joined data...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need just remove argument from `getResult()` (or replace it with default `::HYDRATE_OBJECT`).

Key 'joined table' won't appear but you'll get data structure according to your entities.

Comment: Nope... Instead of multidimensional array i have array of objects...